# how to query database for date = today, except... there is no year

Tags: mysql, date

I have a database with user birthdays... however, the year is not included. so the birthday of a random user would be say 0000-02-03 (feb 3rd).  the column would be of datatype "date"

I want to find that user with a select statement, from today... as in if today was 2012-02-03 I'd want to do something like

```
select * from users where dob = DATE()
```

is this possible without a year?  please inform! thanks

Comment: From [MySQL docs: The DATE Datatype](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html): ***"The supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'."*** How did you manage to store `'0000-02-03'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not as easy as it sounds, as there are leap years, and users having their birthday on 29th February will be returned only in 4 years. It's better return them on 1st March if the 29th February doesn't exists in that year. Actually, if you need to be serious about this, you have to take into account, that every 100 years, there's no leap year, but every 400 there is.

Here is an answer that property takes into account leap-years and will always give you the users whose birthday is on the 29th of February at the same time as those on the 1st of March.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM USERS
  WHERE 
     DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(birthDate),'%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m-%d')
     OR (
            (
                DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y') % 4 <> 0
                OR (
                        DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y') % 100 = 0
                        AND DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y') % 400 <> 0
                    )
            )
            AND DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m-%d') = '03-01'
            AND DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(birthDate),'%m-%d') = '02-29'
        )
```

Comment: hi pentium, this is getting very close, however I tried it an getting 0 results. My DOB column is in the format 0000-02-23. which should return at least 1 result.  any adjustments you can see?

Comment: As far as I know you can't store date objects like that. With 0000, you can't. You probably store in a text column or so. Please pick a year for default, like 2000.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
select * from users where day(dob) = day(CURDATE()) and month(dob) = month(CURDATE());
```

Comment: It doesn't take into account leap years, and 29th february.

Comment: @Pentium10: Good catch. Ironically I provided a leap year solution on SO a few hours ago. (forehead slap) Speaking of which, if you were born on the 29th of Feb. do you have a birthday on non-Leap years?!?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [EXTRACT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract) function to get the day and month parts of a date and compare those to the EXTRACTed day and month of the current date.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to match the month and day like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE MONTH(dob) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND DAY(dob) = DAY(CURDATE())
```

Hopefully, nobody has DOB of Feb. 29th.

Unfortunately, any index on the dob column won't be able to be utilized because we're using a function on the left side of the expressions. If you want to optimize this, you'll want to copy the month and day values into their own columns, with indexes.